# Javascript: Display all the comparison results in a loop in a table form

Tags: javascript, html

My code below might have several matching results but it is now displaying only the last match in the table I have created. How would make a dynamic table so that all the results can be displayed? I am fairly new in javascript so excuse my lack of use of proper terms.

```
              for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                    var obj = result[i];

                    //console.log(obj);

                    var item = obj.item_name;
                    var price = obj.item_price;

                    var re = new RegExp("^.*"+input_item+".*","gi"); 

                    if(item.match(re)){
                        document.getElementById('item_name').innerHTML = item
                        document.getElementById('item_price').innerHTML = price

                    } /*else {
                        alert("doesnt match")
                    }*/



            }
```

Comment: What table? You're overwriting the same two elements each time through the loop.

Comment: Thats what I am asking how do I store the result in a loop and display all the results in a table?

Comment: This a place for a dynamic table. [HTMLTableElement Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) contains everything  you'll need.